# background image auto-scale width fixed height

Tags: html, css

Hi i want an always fit sceen background image and my index page contains 2 div and each of them got specific background image. Combining these 2 div background ima, i will got a full picture (each div bg img got 1/2 of that picture). The problem is the picture aspect ratio is 3:2 (1200x800 resolution) but background-image: cover CSS is auto scale both width and height so if i got different aspect ratio (such as 16:9, 4:3...), the full picture that combined from 2 divs are not right (wrong height from each div bg img). Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Lol. Getting a image by dividing it into 2 parts and then combining them. May I ask why you are doing this? Just set the background-image of the body

Answer (score 0):

`cover` is not the only option for `background-size`. It sounds like you should be doing something like:

```
background-size:auto 100%;
```

Which will set the background images to 100% height, but auto detect the width. Note that you aren't confined to percentages either:

```
background-size:auto 500px;
background-size:auto 31.25em;
```

will also work.

[MDN has a solid reference for all the options available.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: thanks but with background-size:auto 100%, the background image does not scale with bigger resolution (its res is 1200 x800 so if i try bigger width res like 1600, the page shows white space)